# Как изменить значение экземпляра класса или структуры изнутри самого класса или структуры?

Tags: c#, классы, структуры

У меня есть структура, в которой есть поле `Mod`, высчитываемое при инициализации:

```
public struct Characteristic
{
    public CharacteristicType Type;
    public int BaseScore;
    public double Mod;
    public int RacialBonus;
    public int OtherModifier;
    public bool SavingThrow;

    public Characteristic(CharacteristicType type, int score, int rBonus, int oModifier, bool saving)
    {
        Type = type;
        BaseScore = score;
        RacialBonus = rBonus;
        OtherModifier = oModifier;
        SavingThrow = saving;
        if (BaseScore + RacialBonus + OtherModifier > 10)
        {
            Mod = Math.Floor((double) (BaseScore + RacialBonus + OtherModifier - 10) / (double) 2);

        }
        else
            Mod = Math.Round((double) (BaseScore + RacialBonus + OtherModifier - 10) / (double) 2,
                MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    }
}
```

И я хочу написать метод `Up()`, повышающий `BaseScore` на 1 с повторной инициализацией объекта, чтобы я мог написать, к примеру просто `char.Up()` и поле `Mod` изменилось согласно новому значению, но способ с `this = new` не работает:

```
    public void Up()
    {
        this = new Characteristic(Type, BaseScore + 1, RacialBonus, OtherModifier, SavingThrow);
    }
```

Однако работает следующий способ:

```
    public Characteristic Up()
    {
        return new Characteristic(Type, BaseScore + 1, RacialBonus, OtherModifier, SavingThrow);
    }
```

Но это не то, что мне надо, так как для изменения экземпляра мне придётся использовать переприсваивание `char = char.Up()`, а не просто `char.Up()`, как я хочу.
Соответственно вопрос в том, как я могу реализовать свою задумку с переинициализацией экземпляра изнутри класса или структуры?

Comment: `this.Mod = ...` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, я тоже думал об этом, но это копирование кода с повторным высчитыванием `Mod` и как-то не очень красивое решение, так что я думал о том, как я могу повторно вызвать конструктор со всеми имеющимися значениями, увеличив только `BaseScore` на 1

Comment: ну так напишите функцию `calculateMod(...)` и вызывайте её `this.Mod = calcuateMod(...)` где вам надо, и не будет дублирования.

Comment: @tym32167 а, да, точно. Пришлось ещё поменять структуру на класс, чтобы это заработало, но в итоге всё работает как я и хотел. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста, на здоровье.